# Error when converting xml files to json files with help of xml2js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, xml2js

I have about 35000 xml files (7Gb total size) I need to convert to json files.

I have written a conversion script with help of the npm package xml2js.

It complains that I have not a callback function.

Also it looks like there are some issues with memory (FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory).

I'm quite new to JS so I would much appreciate if some one could point me in right direction on how to fix this error.

**code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
const pxmls = path.join(__dirname, 'xml-files');
const pjsons = path.join(__dirname, 'json-files');

function onError(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

// Here's the reading part:
function readFiles(pxmls, onError) {
  fs.readdir(pxmls, (err, filenames) => {
    if (err) {
      onError(err);
      return;
    }
    filenames.forEach((filename) => {
      fs.readFile(`${pxmls}/${filename}`, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        // changing file extension from .xml to .json
        const x = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '.json');
        parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
          fs.writeFile(`${pjsons}/${x}`, JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
readFiles(pxmls);
```

**Error:**

```
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
(node:778) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.

<--- Last few GCs --->

[778:0x103000000]    76652 ms: Mark-sweep 1410.3 (1572.0) -> 1410.1 (1572.0) MB, 84.1 / 0.2 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[778:0x103000000]    76737 ms: Mark-sweep 1410.1 (1572.0) -> 1410.0 (1552.5) MB, 83.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort
[778:0x103000000]    76827 ms: Mark-sweep 1410.0 (1552.5) -> 1410.0 (1552.5) MB, 87.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x9a5c35a9891 <JS Object>
    1: stringSlice(aka stringSlice) [buffer.js:527] [pc=0x36d4804ed77c](this=0x1c76a5982311 <undefined>,buf=0x1b593f84b2a1 <an Uint8Array with map 0x2a3c739b1a61>,encoding=0x9a5c35bd099 <String[5]: utf-8>,start=0,end=524715)
    2: toString [buffer.js:~569] [pc=0x36d48048b5b3](this=0x1b593f84b2a1 <an Uint8Array with map 0x2a3c739b1a61>,encoding=0x9a5c35bd099 <String[5]: utf-8>,start=0x1c76a59823...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: void node::Buffer::(anonymous namespace)::StringSlice<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x36d47ff0437d
[1]    778 abort      node batch_xml_convert_to_json.js
```

Comment: Apart from the memory issue , can you try the above code with just a single file to test for callback not found issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heap space error may indicate a memory leak.  Otherwise, to increase your maximum heap,

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 server.js
```

to start server.js with 8GB heap.

Comment: This might mean you are reading too many files at once. So instead of increasing the heap size, you could go slower, using readFileSync()

Answer (score 1):

your issue is with `fs.writeFile`

```
fs.writeFile(`${pjsons}/${x}`, JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

it needs a callback

```
fs.writeFile(`${pjsons}/${x}`, JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), (writeError) => {
  onError(writeError)
});
```

or more succinctly

```
fs.writeFile(`${pjsons}/${x}`, JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), onError);
```

more info here:
 https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue with the callback. I had to write it like this to have it working.           fs.writeFile(`${pjsons}/${x}`, JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
          });